# How can I add soft delete on laravel mongodb? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3

I get reference from here : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#examples

My model is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent; 
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Message extends Eloquent
{
    use HybridRelations; 
    use SoftDeletes; 
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected  $fillable = ['subject', 'information', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
}
```

My code to insert is like this:

```
Message::create([
    'subject'       => $subject,
    'information'   => $information,
    'created_at'    => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at'    => Carbon::now(),
    'deleted_at'    => null
]);
```

I try run the code, it success insert to table, but I don't find deleted_at field

How to implement softdelete right on laravel mongodb?

Comment: I think if you add the `SoftDeletes` trait it should take care of everything for you. That's what eloquent does normally.

Comment: @apokryfos, If using a mysql database, it was added in the database migration: `$table->timestamps();$table->softDeletes();`. But here I use mongodb database. Where I set it?

Comment: Does MongoDB have a concept of a database schema? I don't think it does, so what you're currently doing should be enough as long as you're consistent.

Comment: Mongodb adds fields when needed.

Comment: @Shady Atef. I set like that. But I don't find deleted_at field

Comment: @apokryfos,It looks like my code is correct, but why is there no deleted_at field

Comment: @mosestoh my guess is it's either obscured by the trait or filtered because it's null. Try running a delete and then querying `Message::withTrashed()` to see if the deleted record has a `deleted_at`

Answer (score 2):

When you use jenssegers/laravel-mongodb and you insert an object (document), the `deteted_at` field is not created. This is created and set with the current date-time when you execute a `delete()` on the object. It is not necessary to assign a `null` value when the object is saved. The library retrieves by default the documents that do not have the field `deleted_at` set, or those that have `null` values, in case the `restore()` method has been previously executed.

Do not forget to `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` in the definition of the model, otherwise, the SoftDelete will not work and it will always return all records.